# Openshift python requests proxy permission denied

Tags: python, proxy, openshift, python-requests

I'm trying to use a proxy with the python 'requests' package on an Openshift server.  I am getting a permission denied error. See below.

Is Openshift blocking the connection or am I not configuring it correctly? Something else?  Openshift doesn't want to let me connect to a proxy because the code works fine locally and on Heroku.

**Code**

```
from ssl import PROTOCOL_TLSv1
import ssladapter

proxies = {'https': 'http://{}:{}@96.44.147.34:6060'.format(CFG.proxy_username, CFG.proxy_password)}

url1 = 'https://reservaciones.volaris.com/Flight/DeepLinkSearch'                    

session = requests.Session()
session.mount('https://', ssladapter.SSLAdapter(ssl_version=PROTOCOL_TLSv1))

request1 = session.get(url1, proxies=proxies)
```

**Traceback**

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='reservaciones.volaris.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Flight/DeepLinkSearch (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4e78386ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 13] Permission denied',)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably OpenShift blocks uncommon outgoing ports for [security reasons](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24310/why-block-outgoing-network-traffic-with-a-firewall). your proxy is listening on 6060. You should try to ssh into your gear and try `telnet`

In my gear, post 6060 is blocked. See the attached screenshot. [portquiz](http://portquiz.net/) listens on all TCP ports.

[image]

Comment: You are correct.  Out of all the proxies I picked I had to pick the one with the port that openshift blocks.  I switched to my socks5 proxies with 1080 ports and they work fine.  Also, thanks for pointing me to portquiz.net :)